# How to print out the output vertically

Tags: java

Basically, the user enters student grades and the program will display and arrange them into sections (0-29 marks, 30-39 marks, 40-69 marks and 70-100 marks). If the user enters anything higher than 100 then the program terminates and outputs the results.

I'm just having trouble printing out the output vertically.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in the students marks. Type above 100 to show output.");

    int marks;
    int starsfrom0to29 = 0;
    int starsfrom30to39 = 0;
    int starsfrom40to69 = 0;
    int starsfrom70to100 = 0;
    int counter = 0;


    marks = input.nextInt();


    while (marks < 100) {

        //PUTTING MARKS INTO CATEGOERY
        if ((marks >= 0) && (marks <= 29)) {
            starsfrom0to29++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 30) && (marks <= 39)) {
            starsfrom30to39++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 40) && (marks <= 69)) {
            starsfrom40to69++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 70) && (marks <= 100)) {
            starsfrom70to100++;
        }

        if (marks < 100) {
            counter++;
        }

       marks = input.nextInt();

    }
    //PRINTING OUT NUMBER OF STARS
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("0-29    ");
    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom0to29; x++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("30-39   ");
    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom30to39; x++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("40-69   ");
    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom40to69; x++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("70-100  ");
    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom70to100; x++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println();
}
```

This prints it out horizontally. E.g: If I typed in the numbers: 23,65,77,87,101 it would display:
0-29    *  
30-39     
40-69   *  
70-100  **

However, I need to find out how to print the output vertically. Basically the stars (asterisks) should be in a vertical line and are below the headlines.

Comment: Can you show what the output currently looks like and what you would like it to look like

Comment: I would but i dont know how to format it because stackoverflow keeps on formatting how i write it and it doesnt show up how i want it to show up. I'll try and post it though

Comment: Use a code block (4 spaces before each line), and the rest of the lines will have their aspect preserved. There is a button in the toolbar that takes a normal block and transforms it to a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a single loop that increments all 4 counters, and prints 1-4 asterisks in the same line in each iteration.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int l = 0;
System.out.println("0-29 30-39 40-69 70-100");
while (i<starsfrom0to29 || j < starsfrom30to39 || k < starsfrom40to69 || l < starsfrom70to100) {
    if (i<starsfrom0to29) {
        System.out.print(" *   ");
        i++;
    } else {
        System.out.print("     ");
    }
    if (j<starsfrom30to39) {
        System.out.print("  *   ");
        j++;
    } else {
        System.out.print("      ");
    }
    if (k<starsfrom40to69) {
        System.out.print("  *   ");
        k++;
    } else {
        System.out.print("      ");
    }
    if (l<starsfrom70to100) {
        System.out.println("  *   ");
        l++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That solved it. I was thinking along those steps but I just didnt know how to write it or where to start from. Theres an error in that code, instead of for loop, I used a while loop.
This task would've been easy if we were allowed to use arrays.

Comment: @user3323950 You're welcome. What was the error? A for loop without initialization and increment (i.e. for(;condition;)) should be equivalent to a while loop. I accepted your edit anyway, since it's clearer this way.

Answer (score 1):

if this is the type of output you are looking for:

```
0-29    
*
*
30-39   
*
*
...
```

swap your `PRINTING OUT NUMBERS OF STARS` code with the following:

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("0-29    ");
for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom0to29; x++) {
    System.out.println("*");
}

System.out.println("30-39   ");
for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom30to39; x++) {
    System.out.println("*");
}

System.out.println("40-69   ");
for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom40to69; x++) {
    System.out.println("*");
}

System.out.println("70-100  ");
for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom70to100; x++) {
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

Comment: you got the right idea but I need the headings on the same line. E.g. 0-29 30-39 40-69 70-100 are all on one line and directly underneath the headings, the asterisk should come up under the relevant heading to what the user typed.

Answer (score 0):

If this the output you are looking for:-

```
Type in the students marks. Type above 100 to show output.
    12
    30
    31
    17
    60
    43  
    89
    97
    100

    0-29    30-39   40-69   70-100


    *        *       *        * 
    *        *       *        *
```

Then here is the java code:-

```
import java.util.*;
public class {
public static void main(String[] args) {



    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in the students marks. Type above 100 to show output.");

    int marks;
    int starsfrom0to29 = 0;
    int starsfrom30to39 = 0;
    int starsfrom40to69 = 0;
    int starsfrom70to100 = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int array[]={0,0,0,0};
   int i=0;
    marks = input.nextInt();


    while (marks < 100) {

        //PUTTING MARKS INTO CATEGOERY
        if ((marks >= 0) && (marks <= 29)) {
            starsfrom0to29++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 30) && (marks <= 39)) {
            starsfrom30to39++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 40) && (marks <= 69)) {
            starsfrom40to69++;
        }

        if ((marks >= 70) && (marks <= 100)) {
            starsfrom70to100++;
        }

        if (marks < 100) {
            counter++;
        }

       marks = input.nextInt();

    }
    //PRINTING OUT NUMBER OF STARS
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("0-29\t30-39\t40-69\t70-100");
    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom0to29; x++) {
    array[0]=array[0]+1;
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom30to39; x++) {
    array[1]=array[1]+1;        
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom40to69; x++) {
    array[2]=array[2]+1;    
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int x = 0; x < starsfrom70to100; x++) {
    array[3]=array[3]+1;
    }
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
if(array[0]>0)
{
System.out.print("*\t");
array[0]=array[0]-1;
}
else System.out.print("\t");
if(array[1]>0)
{
System.out.print("*\t");
array[1]=array[1]-1;
}
else System.out.print("\t");
if(array[2]>0)
{
System.out.print("*\t");
array[2]=array[2]-1;
}
else System.out.print("\t");
if(array[3]>0)
{
System.out.print("*\t");
array[3]=array[3]-1;
}
else System.out.print("\t");
System.out.print("\n");
}


}
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Mind you, there are better ways to handle the whole marks range thing, but I don't know what you are allowed or not allowed to use in your assignment, so I stuck to simple things:

First, you find the maximum number of stars you have. This is in order to know how many rows of stars to print. If you have at most 3 stars, then you'll need to print three lines. If you have 5, then 5, and so on:

```
   // Find max

   int max = 0;
   if ( starsfrom0to29 > max ) {
       max = starsfrom0to29;
   }
   if ( starsfrom30to39 > max ) {
       max = starsfrom30to39;
   }
   if ( starsfrom40to69 > max ) {
       max = starsfrom40to69;
   }
   if ( starsfrom70to100 > max ) {
       max = starsfrom70to100;
   }
```

Now you print the header. The trick here is that each heading has to be the same width. Since the widest is `70-100`, which is six characters wide, 7 with the space, then we have to space each header right-align in a 7 character field.

```
   System.out.println( "   0-29  30-39  40-69 70-100");
```

Now we print the columns. For each range, if there is still a star to be printed at this row (that is, if the number of stars is still greater than the row number), we print the star, right aligned in a 7-character field. If there are no more stars in this column, we just print the spaces.

```
   for ( int i = 1; i <= max; i++ ) {
       if ( starsfrom0to29 >= i ) {
           System.out.print( "      *");
       } else {
           System.out.print( "       ");
       }
       if ( starsfrom30to39 >= i ) {
           System.out.print( "      *");
       } else {
           System.out.print( "       ");
       }
       if ( starsfrom40to69 >= i ) {
           System.out.print( "      *");
       } else {
           System.out.print( "       ");
       }
       if ( starsfrom70to100 >= i ) {
           System.out.print( "      *");
       } else {
           System.out.print( "       ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
```

Note that all of the commands are `System.out.print()` so they don't print end-of-line and just add to the same line. For this reason, when we are finished with a row we need to use one `System.out.println()` to give the end-of-line for the whole row.